# PHP database search issue

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with some code. It's a HTML file that sends a string to a PHP file which then searches an offline database and it returns a link to the html page. Each time I search it states there are no results found.

```css
<?php $searchfor=$_GET['keyword'];
$contents=file_get_contents('/users/tutors/mhtest15/share/shakespeare/home.html', true);
if (stripos($contents, $searchfor) !==false) {
  $startpos=stripos($contents, $searchfor);
  $getcode=substr($contents, $startpos, 150);
  $isolate=explode('"', $getcode);
  $sendlinkback='https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/'.$isolate[1];
  echo "<br> <a href ='".$sendlinkback ."'>The file $searchfor Exists here</a>";
}

else if ($isolate !=='$searchfor') {
  echo "<li>no results to display</li>";
}

?>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>William Shakespeare Archive Search Engine</title>

</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <p>

      <div id="container">
        <center><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fc/20/b4/fc20b40a4447af0bc71746bf47d2849e.jpg" alt="Shakespeare Image" height="400" width="350">

          <h1>Shakespeare Search Engine</h1>

        </center>

        <div style="text-align: center">
          <br>
          <form action='test.php' method="GET" id="search" name="search">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
            <input name='search' style="width:200px;font-size:14pt;" placeholder="Search term...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: You're not using a database....

Comment: As a note, you're looking for the literal string "$searchfor" instead of the value of `$searchfor`

Comment: Sorry I should have said index instead of database. The index is "'/users/tutors/mhtest15/share/shakespeare/home.html'" file

Comment: The name of input is `search`, you try to get `keyword` instead of `search`. that's the first problem :)

Comment: Your input element name is `search` but you `$_GET['keyword']`... That does not work and your if statement isn't correct, you else if test a variable that only exists in the if part.

Comment: Next step and question: Your php file's name is test.php ? :)

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is, you are checking the $_GET['keyword'] variable, but your input name is search.

Change:

```
$searchfor=$_GET['keyword'];
```

To:

```
$searchfor=$_GET['search'];
```

*If you can show us the format of your html file would be great.*

And change file path to this:
https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/

**UPDATE:**

Finally, something like this should work (but it's still ugly)

```
$searchfor=$_GET['search'];
$contents=file_get_contents('https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/', true);

if (stripos($contents, $searchfor) !==false) {
  $startpos=stripos($contents, $searchfor);
  $getcode=substr($contents, $startpos, 150);

  $isolate=explode('"', $getcode);
  $sendlinkback='https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/'.$isolate[0];
  echo "<br> <a href ='".$sendlinkback ."'>The file ".preg_replace('/^>/','',strip_tags($isolate[1]))." Exists here</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised my error pretty quick and felt embarrassed. I've changed it but it's still not working. The relevant HTML code is: 
         <form action='test.php' method="GET" id="search" name="search">
                
                <input name='search' style="width:200px;font-size:14pt;" placeholder="Search term...">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>

Comment: Please provide a workable snippet url with the updated code to check it, and attach the demo format of your html 'database', then we can solve the rest

Comment: The URL is: http://student.computing.dcu.ie/~haynesd2/test.html and the online version of the database can be found at https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william/ . Honestly thank you so much for your help.

Comment: ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/shakespeare/william is equal the file /users/tutors/mhtest15/share/shakespeare/home.html ?

Comment: That's correct. It's the online equivalent of the index I want to search.

Comment: check it are you sure about you have content in $contents.. var_dump($contents)

Comment: That was mentioned above in another comment. I added a var_dump and it returned: string(0) "" . I have added the specific requirements on what I'm supposed to do on the page to make things clearer.

Comment: Okay that is the another problem.. your file path is wrong ... it should be the content of the file instead 0 length string

Comment: Okay so how do I change this? I updated my file path to /users/tutors/mhtest15/share/shakespeare/home.html and it returns "bool(false) ". How do I alter my code to search the content of the file?

Comment: David, we are not here for provide free solutions... learn, try, and ask. You have not even clue what are you doing... this site for coders not for free work..

Comment: Sorry I'm just frustrated with the question. I'm researching boolean returns from php queries to get a better understanding of what the code is returrning